# ¿Cómo integrar actualizaciones o diferencias de una Base de datos SQL en otra base de datos mas completa?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, servidor

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una base de datos SQL Server a la cual le hice una copia de seguridad para trabajarla desde otro PC y hacerle algunas actualizaciones modificando algunos procedimientos almacenados e integrando nuevos procedimientos.

Los usuarios interactúan en la base datos a través de una aplicación de vb.net, ellos ingresan información, editan, eliminan etc

Por ejemplo: Mi base de datos al momento de hacer el backup tenia 3 tablas y 3 Stores Procedures.

Ahora después de trabajarla tengo 4 tablas y 10 stores procedures.

Ahora quiero integrar a la Base de datos antigua, las nuevas actualizaciones que realicé.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer sin necesidad de hacer una restauración total de la base datos? Solo quiero integrar lo nuevo ya que la base datos antigua podría tener datos nuevos insertado por los usuarios que se conectan a ella a través de la app.

Espero haberme explicado de la manera, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: En SSMS existe la opción de exportar la base de datos en un SCRIPT y en este mismo hay cláusulas como DROP IF EXISTS para cada tabla, procedure, trigger, vista, etc. Lo único que harías es correr ese script en tu BD antigua; entiendo que es para un tema de tener tu BD real en una BD de pruebas por tanto temas de administración no tendrían que afectar.

Comment: Pues depende del formato del backup. Si tienes un archivo plano con las sentencias de creación y modificación, pues le añades los cambios. Si es otro formato de backup, integrarle cambios no es trivial y requiere restaurar la BD.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por la respuesta, pero la verdad es que no tengo casi todas las sentencias de creación y hubieron algunos stores procedures que se eliminaron y otros que se actualizaron.

Comment: @lsanchezo Gracias por tu respuesta, me parece interesante lo que dices. O sea que puedo exportar mi BD de pruebas en un Script y ese mismo Script lo ejecuto en mi BD Real y el se encarga de solo integrar lo que no existe. A eso te refires?

Comment: Sí... para que me entiendas mejor, tienes tu base de datos origen (source) en esta tienes que generar el script en SSMS y ejecutas en tu base de datos objetivo (target).

Comment: @lsanchezo la forma de hacer este Script seria: Click derecho sobre la BD / opción Tareas / Generar Scripts... ?

Comment: @JamesJhairToroCantero Redacté los pasos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en los comentarios:

1. Como bien indicas, el primer paso es el seguir la ruta de Tasks/Generate scripts/...

[image]

2. Te saldrá algo parecido a esto si todo está corecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Finalmente el script aparecerá de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta última parte este script solo está para darle al <kbd>**F5**</kbd>

---

**UPDATE:**

Para incluir los `IF EXISTS` tienes que modificar una opción en la ventana de configuración del script:

[image]

Y ahora sí quedaría listo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, gracias. Te quedó perfecto todo... Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y paciencia.